# Is $Y_t = e_t + 0.5(-1)^te_{t-1}$ a stationrary process?

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, time-series, stationary-processes

Given that $e_t$ is a white noise process and $Y_t = e_t + 0.5(-1)^te_{t-1}$, is $\{Y_t\}$ a stationary process?

I can show that
\begin{align*}
    \mu_Y(t) &= E[Y_e]\\
    &=E[e_t + 0.5(-1)^te_{t-1}]\\
    &=E[e_t] + 0.5E[(-1)^te_{t-1}]\\
    &= 0 
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
    \gamma_{Y,t,s} &= Cov(Y_t,Y_s)\\
    &=E[Y_tY_S] - E[Y_t]E[Y_s]\\
    &=E[(e_t + 0.5(-1)^te_{t-1}) (e_s + 0.5(-1)^se_{s-1})]\\
    &=E[e_t]E[e_s]+ 0.5(-1)^sE[e_t]E[e_{s-1}] + 0.5(-1)^tE[e_{t-1}]E[e_s] + 0.25(-1)^{t+s}E[e_{t-1}]E[e_{s-1}]\\
    &=0
\end{align*}
I am not sure if this step is correct:
$$0.5E[(-1)^te_{t-1}] = 0.5(-1)^tE[e_{t-1}]$$
I think it is correct because the randomness comes from $e_{t-1}$.

But if it indeed is, then $\{Y_t\}$  is weakly stationary. But how can I determine whether $\{Y_t\}$ is stationary, i.e the joint distribution of $Y_{t_1},\ldots,Y_{t_n}$ is the same of the joint distribution of $Y_{t_1-k},\ldots,Y_{t_n-k}$?

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, would not you get problems with $(-1)^{t_i-k}$ if for example $t_i$ is odd and $t_i-k$ is pair for example?

Comment: Sorry, would you mind elaborating a little more? With $t_i$ being odd, I can see that $Y_{t_i} = e_{t_i} - 0.5e_{t_i - 1}$, and $Y_{t_i - k} = e_{t_i-k} - 0.5(-1)^{t_i -k}e_{t_i - k - 1}$. It is not clear to me what can be concluded?

Comment: $Y_3=e_3 -0.5e_2$ does not has the same law as $Y_2=e_2 +0.5e_1$ (taking $k=1, t_1=3$ and $n=1$